# Determinant and solution of equations

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, determinant

Solve Question D3 of the image whose link is given below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xS576.jpg
My approach:
I made a matrix of all the coefficients say A (3*3) and then I made a column matrix of variables say X and equated the product of A*X to column matrix B (4,3,3)
Since the condition for infinite solution or no solution is |A|=0
If it has no solution then adjA*B=!0
But this didn’t took me to the answer

Comment: Can you post your system here please?

Comment: The link for image has been provided.. thanks

Comment: Did you consider to calculate $|A|$ and to see when it is zero first?

Comment: To have infinite solutions you shall have det(A)=0 AND the rank of the Total Matrix shall be les than 3.

Comment: I don’t know what is rank i haven’t learnt much about rectangular matrix

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying the second equation by $-1$ and adding to9 the first and doing the same with the last equation we get
$$x+2y+3z=4$$
$$2y-py+z=1$$
$$-2y-\mu z+3z=1$$
Eliminating $z$ we get
$$y(8-3p+\mu p-2\mu)=2+\mu$$
Infinity many solutions we get if $$\mu=-2$$ and $$p=2$$